# How can I solve for a , b , c , d?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, trace, inverse-problems

Let's say I fix a list of two real numbers $\sigma = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2)$, and I want to show that there exists a real, entrywise-nonnegative matrix $A$ with $\sigma$ as its spectrum.

**How could I construct such a matrix?**

My work:

I try to back out the matrix, knowing that I have some constraints to work with, namely, if $\sigma$ were to be the spectrum of $A$, then we must have that

$$\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 = tr(A)$$
$$\sigma_1 \sigma_2 = det(A)$$

Now, looking at the **matrix**

$$ A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

with $a,b,c,d \ge 0$, I compute its eigenvalues to be

$$ \lambda_1, \lambda_2 = \frac{(a+d) \pm \sqrt{(a-d)^2+4bc}}{2} $$

So, in working the problem in reverse, I know that $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ must have the above form.

And that the matrix's entries are to be expressed in terms of $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$.

But the problem is: **how can I actually solve for $a,b,c,d$ ?**  I don't see how the trace and determinant constraint equations are enough to help me construct the matrix.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want the entries to be nonnegative? Then in general there is no solution.

Comment: Hi @Jonas - yes, I am trying to construct the matrix with nonnegative entries only.  I have already solved it, when imposing some structure on the matrix -- looking for a *symmetric* nonnegative matrix that solves this inverse problem is relatively easier.  I am able to compute the symmetric matrix explicitly.  But I just feel that this assumption of symmetry was unnatural, and I wanted to see whether I can construct the matrix in a general case.

Comment: What have you done when $\sigma_1,\sigma_2<0$?

Comment: Hi @Jonas, working the problem in reverse and assuming a solution exists, then I know that I must have $\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 = tr(A) = (a+d) \ge 0$.  So a necessary (but not sufficient) condition is that $\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 \ge 0$.  But I have not treat $\sigma_1$ or $\sigma_2$ individually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sigma_1,\sigma_2\ge0$ then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1 & b\\0 & \sigma_2\end{pmatrix},\quad b\ge0
$$
does it. Suppose $\sigma_1<0$. Since the trace has to be nonnegative, it must be that $\sigma_2\ge-\sigma_1$. You can choose any nonnegative $a,b,c,d$ such that
$$
a+d=\sigma_1+\sigma_2,\quad b\,c=a\,d-\sigma_1\,\sigma_2.
$$
A possible choice is
$$
a=d=\frac{\sigma_1+\sigma_2}{2},\quad b=c=\frac{-\sigma_1+\sigma_2}{2}.
$$

Comment: Hi Professor Aguirre, how do you know to choose $b=ad - \sigma_1 \sigma_2$?  Thanks,

Comment: It is a typo. Should be $b\,c$.

Comment: ah, right!  and one last thing -- you mean $a=d$ in your possible choice, right?  Thanks @JulianAguirre,

Comment: Yes, another typo :-(

Comment: Sorry, *one* last thing, professor:  how do you arrive at your choice for $b,c$?  The choices for $a,d$ are obvious and very natural to choose, however I don't see how your choices of $b,c$ will give $bc = ad - \sigma_1 \sigma_2$ -- what do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Oh....that's assuming $a,d$ are *already* chosen...hmmm...

Comment: Thanks so much, Professor Aguirre!  Have a great day, @JulianAguirre :)